# Escaping space in string - external command

Tags: powershell, escaping

I'm trying to run an external command `(wdsutil.exe)` using `PowerShell`:

```
$parsePref = "--%"
$imageName = "Windows 7 Image"

& wdsutil.exe $parsePref "/Add-Image /Name:$($imageName) /FileName:WDSBoot.wim ..."
```

Returns the error: `An invalid parameter (7) was specified for command /add-image`

Changing `$imageName` to `"Windows7Image"` works (no spaces..) - but this is not desirable.

How can I handle spaces in the `$imageName` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the argument in quotes:

```
& wdsutil.exe $parsePref "/Add-Image /Name:""$($imageName)"" /FileName:WDSBoot.wim ..."
```